# How to iterate over the rows, store the values in a vector and compute a new column with vectors?

Tags: python, pandas

My Pandas dataframe df, looks like this:

```
          Column    

0     0 [
        { “weight": “40", “height": 4,”age”:13 },
        { “weight": “50", “height": 10,”age”:15 },
        { “weight": “30", “height": 5,”age”:25 },
        { “weight": “25", “height”:5,”age”:35 }
        ]

1     1 [
        { “weight": “60", “height": 6, “age":45 },
        { “weight": “80", “height": 8, “age”:30 },
        { “weight": “90", “height": 9, “age”:20 },
        { “weight": “70", “height": 7, “age”:50 }
        ]
```

Output:

```
        weight            height              New_column (compute Weight/Height )
0     (40,50,30,25)     (4,10,5,5)             (10,5,6,5)
1     (60,80,90,70)     (6,8,9,7)             (10,10,10,10)
```

Can anyone please write a pseudocode or an algorithm for this ? I want to do this in pandas. I cannot think of an approach.

Comment: This is a really bad way to use pandas dataframes.... can't you store them as separate columns?

Comment: Another question... do all rows have 4 dicts in them?

Comment: you mean in separate rows? Like the 4 values of the weight can be in separate rows. I can convert my dataframe with lists into another dataframe. But I would want all the values of New_column rows as separate vectors like how I have displayed. No, one row has 1 dict, others has 4 dicts.

Comment: That might be possible... is it guaranteed every vector is size 4? This is important to a simplified solution

Comment: yes, every vector is of size 4.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the data in wide format and still get the desired `weight:height` ratio:

```
orig
                                             Columns
0  [{'weight': '40', 'height': 4, 'age': 13}, {'w...
1  [{'weight': '60', 'height': 6, 'age': 45}, {'w...

def extract(row, field):
    return [int(x[field]) for x in row.Columns]

df = orig.assign(weight=orig.apply(extract, args=("weight",), axis=1).values,
                 height=orig.apply(extract, args=("height",), axis=1).values)

df['ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.weight)/pd.Series(x.height), 
                       axis=1).values.tolist()

df
          height            weight                     ratio
0  [4, 10, 5, 5]  [40, 50, 30, 25]     [10.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.0]
1   [6, 8, 9, 7]  [60, 80, 90, 70]  [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
```